# Actualizar Datagridview cada cierto tiempo C#

Tags: c#, sql

quiero que un datagridview se esté actualizando cada ciertos segundos, usando Timers en C#, los datos los traigo de sql, lo que no sé es si esto va a hacer al sistema mas lento, cualquier recomendación será de gran ayuda, Saludos

Comment: Lectura recomendada antes que te agarren a negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Lo normal es actualizar solo actualizar después de hacer alguna operación pero en caso de que puedan cambiar los datos se pueden usando un Timer(Evidentemente eso hace mas lento si no hay ningun cambio de los datos sino es conveniente) lo que puedes hacer es usar threads o background workers para las operaciones que hagan falta o requieran processamiento i que el timer solo actualize los datos del datagridview

Comment: Es winforms no? cuantos clientes conectados? que tan critico es actualizar "casi en tiempo real"? que tan costosa es la consulta que popula al grid (tiempo, read en disco)? Que version de SQL Server utilizas? u otra DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tienes varias opciones, (seguramente hay otras asi que espemos comentarios y otras respuestas para ampliar). Dependiendo de la criticidad de tu requerimiento de actualizacion son mas complejas de configurar, mantener y sobre todo "realizar deteccion de problemas/errores"

- OPCION 1: "polling"/Sondeo: Puedes hacer el modo "polling" o sea con timers (cada cierto tiempo) con alguna estrategia para no traer datos sino para detectar el cambio y ahi si actualizar datos
- OPCION 1.2: Idem al anterior pero aqui en vez de consultar la query original o tablas que puede ser costoso, se crea una tabla secundaria (podrias ayudarte con Tablas en Memoria de SQL Server) que luego un evento (AFTER INSERT/DELETE etc) actualices esta tabla para detectar un cambio (mas performante consultar esta tabla que la query original y detectar cambio). Esto es mas manual
- OPCION 2: Utilizando [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency). Aqui  la configuracion "subyaciente" y permisos que necesitas en SQL Server es un poco mas completa ya que utiliza SQL Broker
- OPCION 3: Utilizando [SqlNotificationRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190270(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Esto no lo probe pero parece similar al anterior (parece que todo por detras utiliza SQL Broker)

Recomendacion: Si no tienes un equipo/persona que administre e SQL Server con estas configuraciones (o sea que conozca del tema) te propongo la OPCION 1.1 que esta en el medio de todo. Y la mejora con lo nuevo de SQL server tener utilizar en este tipo de tablas que deben "volar" SQL Server In-Memory OLTP (dejo un ejemplo de uso https://github.com/fernandezja/sqlserver-in-memory-oltp-as-queues)

Te puede ayudar estos enlaces

- [Notificaciones de consulta en SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)
- [Planear una estrategia eficaz de notificaciones de consulta y alternativas a las notificaciones de consulta en el artículo planear notificaciones.](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187528(v=sql.105))

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia